# Assign output values to variables

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
import java.lang.System as sys
from time import strftime
cells = AdminConfig.list('Cell').split(lineSeparator)
for cell in cells:
    nodes = AdminConfig.list('Node', cell).split(lineSeparator)
    for node in nodes:
        cname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(cell, 'name')
        nname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(node, 'name')
        servs = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Server,cell=' + cname + ',node=' + nname + ',*').split(lineSeparator)
        if servs != ['']:
            for server in servs:
                sname = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'name')
                ptype = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'processType')
                pid   = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'pid')
                state = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'state')
                apps  = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Application,cell=' + cname + ',node=' + nname + ',process=' + sname + ',*').split(lineSeparator)
                if ( apps != [''] and sname != 'dmgr' ):
                    for app in apps:
                        aname = AdminControl.getAttribute(app, 'name')
                        print aname
```

My request is to list the application names as below.

```
wsadmin>execfile('C:/IBM/pyscripts/applist.py')
TradeWeb_war
ibmasyncrsp
```

So here I want to list the applications as 1, 2, 3 etc and redeploy the application on selection . Please help me to assign the output to a variable for selection.

Comment: This question doesn't give us much to work with. What are your inputs? What is AdminControl?

Comment: List the sample values of `app`

Comment: Hi, Actually Admin control is a mbean in wsadmin of Websphere. By using Admincontrol we query and get the list of application. I am posting the full code here. This is my first question not sure how to edit clearly. Apologies.

Comment: @BaraniKannan The problem isn't about editing. It's about giving us all the information we need to answer your question without having worked on your program for the previous week. Or, better yet, making said knowledge unnecessary, by reducing your question to its core and getting rid of as many domain-specific details as possible. So if parts of your program already work, leave them out and only include some example of the output they give, etc.

Comment: Hi Yes. I understood. Will follow in future. Thanks for feedback, which will always improve me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
for app in apps:
        vars()[str(app)] = AdminControl.getAttribute(app, 'name')
```

Now if the name of `app` was `TradeWeb_war`:

Callling,`TradeWeb_war` will give you the value of:

```
AdminControl.getAttribute(TradeWeb_war, 'name')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for immediate response. I will try this and let you know. Since i am new to Python, need time to understand.